# Only getting single word parameters from Alexa Skills Kit

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I'm writing an Alexa Skill, and I can only get single word parameters into my code.

Here is the intent schema:

```
    {
  "intents": [
    {
      "intent": "HeroQuizIntent",
      "slots": [
        {
          "name": "SearchTerm",
          "type": "SEARCH_TERMS"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "intent": "HeroAnswerIntent",
      "slots": [
        {
          "name": "SearchTerm",
          "type": "SEARCH_TERMS"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "intent": "AMAZON.HelpIntent"
    }
  ]
}
```

and my sample utterances are:

```
HeroQuizIntent quiz me
HeroAnswerIntent is it {SearchTerm}
```

For the HeroAnswerIntent, I'm checking the SearchTerm slot, and I'm only getting single words in there.

So, "Peter Parker" gives "Parker", "Steve Rogers" gives "Rogers", and "Tony Stark" gives "Stark".

How do I accept multiple words into a slot?

Comment: Any clues in the json structure you get?  Nothing obvious. It might be worth posting the structure.

Comment: Good point.  Here's the pertinent portion of the request being sent to Lamda.

Comment: `"request": {
    "type": "IntentRequest",
    "requestId": "EdwRequestId.da0c74ea-15bd-45b9-a69e-76c523f08195",
    "timestamp": "2016-04-08T18:04:45Z",
    "intent": {
      "name": "HeroAnswerIntent",
      "slots": {
        "SearchTerm": {
          "name": "SearchTerm",
          "value": "Parker"
        }
      }
    }
  },
`

Comment: So, the SearchTerm slot still has just the last work of the what I'm telling Alexa.  Seems like the issue would be in the Alexa voice interpretation then, and the only solution might be to accept multiple slots.  That would be sad as it would make for some hellish logic in the lamda function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to change the Slot type to AMAZON.LITERAL.

The trick was that in the sample utterances, I also had to provide multiple utterances to demonstrate the minimum and maximum sizes of literals that Alexa should interpret.  It's wonky, but works.

Here's the reference for it:  https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/alexa-skills-kit-interaction-model-reference

Answer (score 3):

I've had same problem with my skill and that's the only solution which is worked for my skill to use several words, but you need to check are these slots not empty and concatenate them

Intent schema:

```
{
  "intent": "HeroAnswerIntent",
  "slots": [
    {
      "name": "SearchTermFirst",
      "type": "SEARCH_TERMS"
    },
    {
      "name": "SearchTermSecond",
      "type": "SEARCH_TERMS"
    },
    {
      "name": "SearchTermThird",
      "type": "SEARCH_TERMS"
    }
  ]
},
```

Sample utterance

`HeroAnswerIntent is it {SearchTermFirst}
HeroAnswerIntent is it {SearchTermFirst} {SearchTermSecond}
HeroAnswerIntent is it {SearchTermFirst} {SearchTermSecond} {SearchTermThird}`

And last one you need to put every of your words in separate line in SEARCH_TERMS slot definition

**Also using AMAZON.LITERAL sometimes not pass variable into skill at all even if you test it using service simulator (skill console, test tab)**

Answer (score 1):

The solution @Xanxir mentioned works equivalently with the newer [custom slots](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/migrating-to-the-improved-built-in-and-custom-slot-types#replacing-literal-with-custom-slot-types) format. In this case, you'd just put multiple length examples in your custom list of values for your slot type.

Answer (score 0):

AMAZON.SearchQuery

So you can use this in your utterances, and it will detect all words that the user speaks in between, Its rather accurate

It will solve your problem.

Ref Link: [Alexa SearcQuery](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/slot-type-reference.html#amazonsearchquery)